# Update models from database messes up mappings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I've got an issue with my .NET project where when I update my models from database and select "Add" and select my new table, 2800 errors are produced such as "'Agreement' does not contain a definition for 'AgreementContactHistories' and no extension method'AgreementContactHistories' accepting a first argument of type 'Agreement' Could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

This also happens when refreshing models.

What could be causing all these errors to occur? All I want to do is be able to update my models from the database and each time I try I get this problem

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

Please check the below points which might reslove your issues.

1)Need to Give proper relations in a tables, i.e. Primary to forign key relationships.

2) Please check your edmx design, if any table added twice(ex: tblassignment, tblassignment1 )

3) Make sure that You are using the same name as namespace while you give the name when generate the model.

If above are not helpful to you, post us some screenshots or explian your excat problem.